# Python regex - why does end of string ($ and \Z) not work with group expressions?

Tags: python, regex

In Python 2.6. it seems that markers of the end of string `$` and `\Z` are not compatible with group expressions. Fo example

```
import re
re.findall("\w+[\s$]", "green pears")
```

returns

```
['green ']
```

(so `$` effectively does not work). And using

```
re.findall("\w+[\s\Z]", "green pears")
```

results in an error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/re.pyc in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    175 
    176     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 177     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    178 
    179 if sys.hexversion >= 0x02020000:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/re.pyc in _compile(*key)
    243         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    244     except error, v:
--> 245         raise error, v # invalid expression
    246     if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
    247         _cache.clear()

error: internal: unsupported set operator
```

**Why does it work that way and how to go around?**

Comment: `so $ effectively does not work` -- What is your expected output??

Comment: @RohitJain `['green ', 'pears']` (as from `'\w+\s'` plus `'\w+$'`).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A `[..]` expression is a *character group*, meaning it'll match any one character contained therein. You are thus matching a literal `$` character. A character group always applies to one input character, and thus can never contain an anchor.

If you wanted to match either a whitespace character *or* the end of the string, use a non-capturing group instead, combined with the `|` or selector:

```
r"\w+(?:\s|$)"
```

Alternatively, look at the `\b` word boundary anchor. It'll match anywhere a `\w` group start or ends (so it anchors to points in the text where a `\w` character is preceded or followed by a `\W` character, or is at the start or end of the string).

Comment: @EMS: That's because the `:` in my expression was a typo; corrected.

Comment: ...because of my typo, sorry for that.

Comment: I think you mean a **non-capturing** group.  This stuff is confusing enough as it is; let's at least try and use the terminology correctly.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Yes, indeed I did mean non-capturing. Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Square brackets don't indicate a group, they indicate a character set, which matches *one* character (any one of those in the brackets)  As [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), "special characters lose their special meaning inside sets" (except where indicated otherwise as with classes like `\s`).

If you want to match `\s` or end of string, use something like `\s|$`.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Pieters' answer is correct. To elaborate a bit, if you use capturing groups

```
r"\w+(\s|$)"
```

you get:

```
>>> re.findall("\w+(\s|$)", "green pears")
[' ', '']
```

That's because `re.findall()` returns the captured group `(\s|$)` values.

[Parentheses `()` are used for two purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195624/1241108): character groups and captured groups. To disable captured groups but still act as character groups, use `(?:...)` syntax:

```
>>> re.findall("\w+(?:\s|$)", "green pears")
['green ', 'pears']
```